# JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry - Could not find matching type descriptor for requested Java class

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a project running with no problem except this warning message:

```
WARN  org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry - Could not find matching type descriptor for requested Java class [java.util.List]; using fallback enviroment
```

Why am I getting this message? How can I disable it?

I'm using:

```
spring webmvc 4.2.1
hibernate-core 5.0.1
```

This message appears since I'm using JPA 2.1 AttributeConverter.

Comment: Having the same issue; I'm using 10+ AttributeConverters, but only two of them seems to be affected. The other AttributeConverters convert from simple type to database column (e.g. array), but these two use complex types (e.g. POJOs) to String (Json) conversion.

Answer (score 19):

You get this warning if the type your converter is supposed to convert does not implement `Serializable`, is not an `enum` nor [one of the types](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d65829502542444f7a04ae10eabdea24865c61ad/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry.java#L31) Hibernate knows how to convert. As soon as you make the type your converter is supposed to convert `Serializable`, the warning goes away.

Looking through the Hibernate code, the purpose of a `JavaTypeDescriptor` seems to be to provide information on how to serialize certain types and whether or how it's possible to do deep copies. Because Hibernate doesn't know anything about the type, [it makes some guesses](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d65829502542444f7a04ae10eabdea24865c61ad/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry.java#L132). If you like, you can help Hibernate by supplying a `JavaTypeDescriptor` yourself. There's a [Singleton](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d65829502542444f7a04ae10eabdea24865c61ad/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry.java#L27) for that.

Comment: simply making the type `Serializable` will make Hibernate use byte array comparison of serialized objects for dirty checking (among other things). so be sure to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 14):

While both the answers are logical and correct none address the actual issue in the question above!

You are getting this error for `java.util.List`, neither can you write equals/hashcode implementations, nor extend `Serializable`, and defining a `AbstractTypeDescriptor` is pointless here.

You are getting this error simply because interface List is not `Serializable` in Java and you will have to choose an implementation which is.

The concrete types like `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are `Serializable`, you can either use them (breaking interface-based programming) or create your own List implementations that extend/implement `Serializable` (none of the built-in concrete `List` implementations can be used then).

Answer (score 10):

As of Hibernate 5.2.7 (Jan 24th, 2017) this warning changed to:

> WARN  org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry -
>   HHH000481: Encountered Java type [class SomeClass] for which
>   we could not locate a JavaTypeDescriptor and which does not appear to
>   implement equals and/or hashCode.  This can lead to significant
>   performance problems when performing equality/dirty checking involving
>   this Java type. Consider registering a custom JavaTypeDescriptor or
>   at least implementing equals/hashCode.

So, there are these solutions:

1) Make sure your type implements `equals` and `hashcode`, and also annotate it with `Immutable.class` in case it is immutable. Hibernate will use the fallback ([defined here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d65829502542444f7a04ae10eabdea24865c61ad/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry.java#L132)).

2) Implement a specific java-type-descriptor, like `SomePersistentClassTypeDescriptor`:

```
JavaTypeDescriptorRegistry.INSTANCE
                          .addDescriptor(new SomePersistentClassTypeDescriptor());
```

You can extend `AbstractTypeDescriptor`. An example if your type is immutable:

```
public class SomePersistentClassTypeDescriptor
      extends AbstractTypeDescriptor<SomePersistentClass> {

    public SomePersistentClassTypeDescriptor() {
        super(SomePersistentClass.class);
        }

    @Override
    public String toString(SomePersistentClassvalue) {
        return (value == null) ? null : value.toString();
        }

    @Override
    public SomePersistentClassfromString(String string) {
        return (string == null) ? null : SomePersistentClass.getInstance(string);
        }

    @Override
    public <X> X unwrap(SomePersistentClass value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null) return null;
        else if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return (X)value.toString();
            }
        else throw unknownUnwrap(type);
        }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public <X> SomePersistentClass wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options)
        {
        if (value == null) return null;
        if (String.class.isInstance(value)) {
            return SomePersistentClass.getInstance(((String)value));
            }
        throw unknownWrap(value.getClass());
        }
    }
```

If your type, however, is mutable, provide your own `MutabilityPlan`:

```
public class SomePersistentClassTypeDescriptor
      extends AbstractTypeDescriptor<SomePersistentClass> {

    public SomePersistentClassTypeDescriptor() {
        super(SomePersistentClass.class, new MyMutabilityPlan());
        }
...
}
```

3) Make `SomePersistentClass` implement Serializable. Then Hibernate will use byte array comparison of the serialized object for dirty checking etc, which is not very nice.

---

Also, see:

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10858
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11391 (for the future Hibernate 6.0).